Horizontal paging in the WebView is not working perfectly on Xiaomi devices
The ePub reader utilizes a WebView and JavaScript for horizontal book reading, but the pages are not divided perfectly on Xiaomi devices. Other devices are functioning correctly. Here is the reference indicating the issue we're encountering on Xiaomi devices with the WebView, using the below JavaScript function.(Issue)
function initHorizontalDirection(deviceName) {

    preInitHorizontalDirection();
    postInitHorizontalDirection(deviceName);

}

function preInitHorizontalDirection() {

    //console.log(window);
    //console.log("-> " + document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText);
    var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    // Required when initHorizontalDirection() is called multiple times.
    // Currently it is called only once per page.
    htmlElement.style.width = null;
    bodyElement.style.width = null;
    htmlElement.style.height = null;
    bodyElement.style.height = null;

    var bodyStyle = bodyElement.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(bodyElement);
    var paddingTop = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingTop, 10);
    var paddingRight = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingRight, 10);
    var paddingBottom = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingBottom, 10);
    var paddingLeft = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingLeft, 10);
    //console.log("-> padding = " + paddingTop + ", " + paddingRight + ", " + paddingBottom + ", " + paddingLeft);

    //document.documentElement.clientWidth is window.innerWidth excluding x scrollbar width
    var pageWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - (paddingLeft + paddingRight);
    //document.documentElement.clientHeight is window.innerHeight excluding y scrollbar height
    var pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight - (paddingTop + paddingBottom);

    bodyElement.style.webkitColumnGap = (paddingLeft + paddingRight) + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.webkitColumnWidth = pageWidth + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.columnFill = 'auto';

    htmlElement.style.height = (pageHeight + (paddingTop + paddingBottom)) + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.height = pageHeight + 'px';
}

function postInitHorizontalDirection(deviceName) {

    var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var bodyStyle = bodyElement.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(bodyElement);
    var paddingTop = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingTop, 10);
    var paddingRight = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingRight, 10);
    var paddingBottom = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingBottom, 10);
    var paddingLeft = parseInt(bodyStyle.paddingLeft, 10);
    var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    var scrollWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
    if (scrollWidth > clientWidth
        && scrollWidth > document.documentElement.offsetWidth) {
//        if (deviceName.toString().toLowerCase().includes("poco") || deviceName.toString().toLowerCase().includes("xiaomi")) {
//            scrollWidth -= paddingRight;
//        } else {
            scrollWidth += paddingRight;
//        }
    }
    var newBodyWidth = scrollWidth - (paddingLeft + paddingRight);
    window.scrollWidth = scrollWidth;

    htmlElement.style.width = scrollWidth + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.width = newBodyWidth + 'px';

    // pageCount deliberately rounded instead of ceiling to avoid any unexpected error
    var pageCount = Math.round(scrollWidth / clientWidth);
    var pageCountFloat = scrollWidth / clientWidth;

    if (pageCount != pageCountFloat) {
        console.warn("-> pageCount = " + pageCount + ", pageCountFloat = " + pageCountFloat
            + ", Something wrong in pageCount calculation");
    }

    FolioPageFragment.setInitHorizontalDirectionSuccessfully(pageCount);
}

ExpecingLike This
